# angular2 can't set object inside observable subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a constructor where i get the id that comes from the url. then i have this in the ngInit:

```
  ngOnInit() { 
this.as.getPostById(this.postId).subscribe(
  (post) => {
    this.thepost = post;
    console.log(this.thepost);
    this.meta['title'] = 'title of the post';
    this.meta['metaTitle'] = 'meta tag title';
    this.meta['metaDesc'] = 'dynamic description for post';
    this.meta['metaKeywords'] = 'dynamic,keywords,post';
    this.meta['ogTitle'] = 'post title';
    this.meta['ogDesc'] = 'dynamic description to share post';
    this.meta['ogImg'] = '/assets/images/postimage.jpg';
    this.meta['ogUrl'] = '/post/idpost';
  }
);
//console.log(this.thepost);
// this.meta['title'] = 'title of the post';
// this.meta['metaTitle'] = 'meta tag title';
// this.meta['metaDesc'] = 'dynamic description for post';
// this.meta['metaKeywords'] = 'dynamic,keywords,post';
// this.meta['ogTitle'] = 'post title';
// this.meta['ogDesc'] = 'dynamic description to share post';
// this.meta['ogImg'] = '/assets/images/postimage.jpg';
// this.meta['ogUrl'] = '/post/idpost';
}
```

if i set the meta object inside the subscribe it doesn't work. but outside the meta tags does change. bizzare this is with this.thepost. i set it within the subscribe, and i can use it in the template, but when i log it outside of the subscribe, it is undefined.

what am i'm missing here?

let me add the entire code i have at the moment:

```
import { Component, OnInit,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit,Renderer } from      '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/RX';
import {AppService} from '../services/app.service';
import { MetaSetterService } from '../services/meta-setter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit {

  subscription: Subscription;
  postId:String;
  thepost;
  meta:Object = {};
  post;
  postTitle:String;

  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private activeR: ActivatedRoute,
    private as:AppService,
    private metaSetter:MetaSetterService,
    public renderer:Renderer
  ) {

    this.subscription = this.activeR.params.subscribe(
      (param:any) => {
        this.postId = param['id'];
      }
    )
   }

  ngOnInit() { 
     this.as.getPostById(this.postId).subscribe(
      (post) => {
        this.thepost = post;
        console.log(this.thepost);
        this.postTitle = post.title;
        this.meta['title'] = 'title of the post';
        this.meta['metaTitle'] = 'meta tag title';
         this.meta['metaDesc'] = 'dynamic description for post';
         this.meta['metaKeywords'] = 'dynamic,keywords,post';
        this.meta['ogTitle'] = 'post title';
        this.meta['ogDesc'] = 'dynamic description to share post';
        this.meta['ogImg'] = '/assets/images/postimage.jpg';
        this.meta['ogUrl'] = '/post/idpost';
      }
    );
    //console.log(this.thepost);
    // this.meta['title'] = 'title of the post';
    // this.meta['metaTitle'] = 'meta tag title';
    // this.meta['metaDesc'] = 'dynamic description for post';
    // this.meta['metaKeywords'] = 'dynamic,keywords,post';
    // this.meta['ogTitle'] = 'post title';
    // this.meta['ogDesc'] = 'dynamic description to share post';
    // this.meta['ogImg'] = '/assets/images/postimage.jpg';
    // this.meta['ogUrl'] = '/post/idpost';
  }



  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit():void{
    this.metaSetter.setAll(this.renderer,this.meta);
  }


}
```

Comment: Why did you expect it to be defined outside the subscribe? It doesn't exist until the callback gets called, *that's why you write a callback*.

Answer (score 0):

The commented-out code is executed before the data arrives from your `as.getPostById().subscribe()` call. That's the nature of async execution.

You need to move code that depends on the response move inside the `subscribe(...)` callback.

Comment: A search for duplicates indicates that you've answered this question a lot...

Comment: There are some kind of questions where I find it hard to search for duplicates and stopped searching. Perhaps I'm searching the wrong keywords ...

Comment: I went with *"angular 2 subscribe log undefined site:stackoverflow.com"* in Google, found quite a few!

Comment: hi. that's what i thought. but how can i populate the meta object which i have: and then use it?

Comment: Use it how? . . .

Comment: the idea is: i get the content of a specific post. the i set the meta object and then send it in the life cycle of ngAfterInit like so:   ngAfterViewInit():void{
    this.metaSetter.setAll(this.renderer,this.meta);
  }

Comment: If other code depends on the reponse, then use `map` instead of return (results in an `Observable` instead of a `Subscription` and pass it where you need the response and do the `subscribe()` there. Search for Observable tutorials for Angular2.